# Expected squared error of example of James-Stein estimator

Tags: estimation, least-squares, regularization

Efron and Hastie give an introductory example to compare the James-Stein estimator vs the standard MLE. This is from their book Computer Age Statistical Inference (downloadable for free) on pages 91 and 92. Here is the statement of the scenario:

Suppose we wish to estimate a single parameter $\mu$ from observation $x$ in the Bayesian situation

$$\mu \sim N(M, A)$$

and

$$x|\mu\sim N(\mu,1).$$

This implies that $\mu$ has the posterior distribution

$$\mu|x \sim N(M+B(x-M),B),$$

where $B=A/(A+1)$.

The Bayes estimator of $\mu$ (denoted by $\hat{\mu}^{\mathrm{B}}$) is $M + B(x-M)$.

My question is around their stated expected squared error of this estimator. They state that the expected squared error of this estimator is $B$, i.e. $E\lbrace(\hat{\mu}^{\mathrm{B}}-\mu)^2\rbrace=B$.

I do not understand how they derived that. I am not sure whether my derivation is incorrect because of major or minor logical flaws (or both).

I attempted to derive the expected squared error formula as follows. As I understand it, the expectation is wrt $X$ conditional on a fixed $\mu$. Accordingly, 
$$E\lbrace(\hat{\mu}^{\mathrm{B}}-\mu)^2\rbrace=\int_{S_X}(\hat{\mu}^{\mathrm{B}}-\mu)^2f_{x|\mu}(x)dx,$$
where $S_X$ is the support of $X$.
Replacing $\hat{\mu}^{\mathrm{B}}$ with its formula, we have
$$E\lbrace(\hat{\mu}^{\mathrm{B}}-\mu)^2\rbrace=\int_{S_X}[(M+B(x-M))-\mu]^2f_{x|\mu}(x)dx.$$
Adding in $Bu-Bu$ under the square exponent, we have
$$E\lbrace(\hat{\mu}^{\mathrm{B}}-\mu)^2\rbrace=\int_{S_X}[(M-\mu+B\mu-BM)+Bx-B\mu]^2f_{x|\mu}(x)dx.$$
Letting $K=M-\mu+B\mu-BM$ and multiplying out square factor, 
$$E\lbrace(\hat{\mu}^{\mathrm{B}}-\mu)^2\rbrace=\int_{S_X}[K^2-K(Bx-B\mu)+(Bx-B\mu)^2]f_{x|\mu}(x)dx.$$
We can then split the integral into three separate integrals based on the terms in the square brace above. Clearly $$\int_{S_X}K^2f_{x|\mu}dx=K^2$$. Furthermore, $$\int_{S_X}K(Bx-B\mu)f_{x|\mu}dx=0,$$ since $E_{x|u}\lbrace X \rbrace=\mu$. Finally,
$$\int_{S_X}(Bx-B\mu)^2f_{x|\mu}(x)dx=B^2,$$
since $Var\lbrace X \rbrace=1$. Putting the above together, we have
$$E\lbrace(\hat{\mu}^{\mathrm{B}}-\mu)^2\rbrace=K^2+B^2.$$ 
$K^2=(M-\mu+B\mu-BM)^2=[(1-B)(M-\mu)]^2$ represents the offset penalty (that increases the further $\mu$ is from $M$) and $B^2$ represents sampling variability in $X$. 
If you take the expectation with the above wrt the prior dbn of $u$ (i.e. do not condition on a fixed $\mu$), then you obtain
$$(1-B)^2A + B^2$$.
Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I simply failed to simplify the final line.

Since $B=A/(A+1)$, we have that

$$A=B/(1-B).$$

Substituting the above formula for $A$ into the final line, we have that

$$E\lbrace (\hat{\mu}^{\mathrm{B}}-\mu)^2\rbrace=(1-B)^2\frac{B}{1-B}+B^2.$$

After simplifying, we get

$$E\lbrace (\hat{\mu}^{\mathrm{B}}-\mu)^2\rbrace=B.$$

Comment: I still don't get it. Is this really the way to solve this?